# trigger CSS transform via jQuery on element that was changed from display:none to display block not working - requires timeout

Tags: jquery, css, triggers, transform

I have an element that is normally hidden via CSS (style sheet) with

`display:none;`

The element will be made visible via jQuery:

`$('#element-id').css('display','block');`

immediately after that statement, I set a CSS class at the parent element, which triggers the transformation:

`$('#parentdiv').addClass('trigger-animation');`

The issue is that the browser seems to not get enough time to process the inline CSS style - render the element visible - and then apply the transformation.

If I put the "addClass" statement in a "setTimeout(function){};" and give the browser like 25ms to process / render the element, it works. It even works with just 0 ms - but I want to know why as I would like to rely on this solution to work in every browser.

`setTimeout(function(){ $('#parentdiv').addClass('trigger-animation'); },25);`

It even works with just 1 ms - but the question is: Is there a better / safe solution to this? How can I find out, when the browser has rendered the "display:block;" which seems to be required in order to trigger the transformation.

Here is a minimal reproducable example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ProFuel mobiles menü</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        
        #mblnv {
            position: relative;
            width: 250px;
            height: 100vh;            
            background: #852470;
            /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        
        #mblnv ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        #mblnv ul li {
            list-style: none;
        }
        
        ul.mblnv-lvl-1 a.mblnv-heading {
            font-weight: 700;
        }
        
        .mblnv-lvl-0{
            
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background: #852470;
        }
        
        .mblnv-lvl-0 {
            left: 0;
            transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.1s;
        }
        
        .mblnv-lvl-0 > li > a
         {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(100px);
            display: block;
            padding: 8px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #600f4e;            
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 20px;
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        
        
        .mblnv-lvl-0-open .mblnv-lvl-0 > li > a
        {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0);
        }   
                
        #helper {
            background: orange;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 1000;
            
        }
        #helper a{
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        

        .mblnv-transition-style-style-3{transition:transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.28s,opacity 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.37s;}
        .mblnv-transition-style-style-2{transition:transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.21s,opacity 1s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.85, 0.45, 1) 0.30s;}
        .mblnv-transition-style-style-1{transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.85, 0.45, 1) 0.1s, opacity 1s cubic-bezier(0.24, 0.88, 0.53, 1) 0.2s;}
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="mblnv">
        <ul class="mblnv-lvl-0">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="mblnv-animation-slide-up-reveal mblnv-transition-style-style-1">Menu Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="mblnv-lvl-0-to-lvl-1-link mblnv-animation-slide-up-reveal mblnv-transition-style-style-2">Menu Item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="mblnv-animation-slide-up-reveal mblnv-transition-style-style-3">Menu Item 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div id="helper">
        <a href="#" id="nav-open">Nav open no animation</a><br><br>
        <a href="#" id="nav-open-2">Nav open with animation</a>

    </div>
    
    
    <script>
        
        // no animation
        
        $('#nav-open').click(function(){
            $('.mblnv-lvl-0').css('display','block');
            $('#mblnv').addClass('mblnv-lvl-0-open');
        });
       
        // animation
        
        $('#nav-open-2').click(function(){
            $('.mblnv-lvl-0').css('display','block');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#mblnv').addClass('mblnv-lvl-0-open');
            },0);
        });
        
       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also tried to observe changes to the element with the "MutationObserver" and then trigger the "addClass" function in the callback function of the MutationsObserver. That doesn't work either.

Comment: Please could you give a bit more detail preferably create a runnable snippet. What is the transformation? My guess is that it will work even if you wait for 0s, i.e. just get a refresh, but I cant be sure. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, 0 ms works as well. I provided a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The why is just that the browser has been asked to rerender the page so the display setting takes effect.